# Zoom issue with Canon 24-105 f4 L

Tags: canon

My 24-105 works perfectly from 40-105 but will not go to 24mm on the zoom and to macro on focus, any ideas please? The zoom ring sticks at about 40mm.

Answer (score 3):

> My lens will not go below 40mm, it will not get to 24mm. Any ideas are welcomed me please.

Don't try to force it. Send it to Canon for service.